# How to install specific version of java

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, yum, apt

My current java version is `11.0.12` . I want to install `11.0.13` so I tried with `update-alternatives --config java` but there is no 13 version.

I also check with installable java version by `apt search "OpenJDK"` , it show

- openjdk-11-jdk 11.0.12
- openjdk-8-jdk 8u312

So I don't know how to find `11.0.13` installer package ?

PS - I don't want to install by local downloaded file.

Comment: You will need to pull and build it yourself or source it elsewhere if your package manager doesn't have it.

Comment: I have no idea why it's not showing up for you, relevant link to 11.0.13: https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/openjdk-11-jdk

Answer (score 1):

`update-alternatives --config java` command only works when you have different Java major versions installed in different paths, such as a jdk8 and an 11.

Try updating your repository with `sudo apt update` and then check with `apt list openjdk-11-jdk`.

What version of Ubuntu do you have?